# Embed Cordova WebView in a Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: cordova, windows-10

Is it possible to embed the Cordova webview in a Windows 10 Universal App?

There are guides to embed cordova into iOS and Android apps.
But I can't find one to do the same for windows 10 universal apps.

I know that you can create windows 10 apps with cordova.
But what I want is to use cordova only in a certain webview and not for the whole app.

Edit 1:
I want to use Cordova and not a regular webview because I am trying to integrate a Cordova project into another application. Since this Cordova project uses some Cordova Plugins (for example to access the filesystem) it would be very difficult / time consuming to rewrite all Cordova functions to Javascript code that works within the webview.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? If so, please edit your post and add your code

Comment: Well I don't know where to start. If you create an iOS or Android Cordova project you can see the classes cordova adds. Then on Android for example you can do "public class MyActivity extends CordovaActivity" and change / alter / embed Cordova the way you like. But since Cordova is officially supported as a project type in visual studio there seem to be no .xaml / .cs files that I could have a look at.

Comment: I am not 100% sure this is possible based on the research I've done so far. But is there a specific reason that you want to use Cordova, and not simply an embedded WebView? You may want to highlight that in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I adjusted my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminK. did you manage to find a solution? I'm having the same issue as I'm trying to add Cordova to an existing Windows Universal App.

Comment: @Nicholas, no I didn't find a solution :/

Comment: @BenjaminK. Did you get any solution? I need to use Cordova 6.4.0 in my existing UWP application.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS No I never found a solution. I think there is none.